# React Native - Resetting setInterval duration when array.length.current == 0 or when array becomes empty

Tags: arrays, reactjs, setinterval

I have a function that adds numbers to an array and then plays the sounds of the numbers and then removes the numbers after they are played at an interval called 'delay'.  However, I have trouble figuring out where to reset the delay back to 0.  That is - when all the numbers are played and removed from the array.  The whole point of this is so that the first number being added will always be played immediately (at 0 second delay), while numbers being added afterwards will be played and removed at an interval like 4 seconds.  I have spent a lot of time on solving this problem, but can anyone figure out where to reset the delay back to 0 so that when the array is empty, the first number being added will always be played immediately?  Remember that if you keep adding numbers, the numbers will wait at an interval like 4 seconds to being played, like a sound queue.

```
const [arr, setArr] = React.useState([]); //Sound queue array
const interval = React.useRef(null);
const arr_length = React.useRef(null);
const [delay, setDelay] = useState(0);

function set_remove_arr_interval(num) {

setArr((currentNumbers) => [...currentNumbers, num]);
if (!interval.current) {

  interval.current = setInterval(() => {
    // Sets an ongoing interval for the sound queue
    console.log("Array current position: " + arr_length.current);

    if (arr_length.current > 0) {
      playSound(arr[0][0], arr[0][1], arr[0][2]);
      setDelay(4000); //My delay duration at 4 seconds
    }

    if (arr_length.current === 0) {
      // setDelay(0); // <-- I tried resetting the delay duration here to 0 but it resets to 0 every time a number is entered immediately and plays it, which is not what I want.
      clearInterval(interval.current);
      interval.current = null;
      return;
    }
    arr_length.current = arr_length.current - 1;

    setArr((currentNumbers) => [...currentNumbers.slice(1)]);

  }, delay);

 }

}

function add(num) {
arr_length.current = arr.length + 1;
set_remove_arr_interval(num);
}
```

Edit: I also tried initialising a new variable called isFirst, but it only works at alternating times of the interval:

```
    const [isFirst, setIsFirst] = useState(true);

    if (isFirst == false && arr_length.current == 0) {
      setDelay(0);
      setIsFirst(true);
    }

    if (arr_length.current > 0) {
      playSound(arr[0][0], arr[0][1], arr[0][2]);
      if (isFirst == true) {
        setDelay(4000);
        setIsFirst(false);
      }
    }
```

Comment: To clarify on this problem, I want the delay duration to reset to 0 when the arr_length.current changes from 1 to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I now solved the problem by simply resetting the delay back to 0 using the useState hook when the array's length is at 1.  Does anybody have a better solution than this? Because I believe hooks are not encouraged to be used inside functions and I also found out that sometimes console.logging them does not log the new state when changed.

```
sound.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(async (status) => {
      if (status.didJustFinish === true) {
        const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(data[0], {
          shouldPlay: true,
        });
        setSound(sound);
        await sound.playAsync();
        if (arr.length == 1) {
          setDelay(0);
        }
      }
    });
```